# Windows + Eclipse + ARM-GCC

Tags: eclipse, compiler-errors, arm

I would like to use eclipse IDE for my development with Tiva (LM4F) processor. I did this tutorial. [Kernel hacks tutorial](http://kernelhacks.blogspot.hu/2012/11/the-complete-tutorial-for-stellaris_25.html).

I use Win 8.1 x64 + eclipse + ARM-GCC and I would like to program a LM4F MCU.
I sat up everything, compiler path, the driverlib path. But It can't find the correct dependencies

`Invoking: Cross GCC Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc -DPART_LM4F120H5QR -DTARGET_IS_BLIZZARD_RA1 -DARM_MATH_CM4 -I../..  /../stellarisware/ -I../../../stellarisware/utils -I../../../stellarisware/driverlib -I../../../stellarisware/inc/ -O0 -g3 -Wall -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.c"
c:/gnu_gcc_arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv7e-m/softfp\libg.a(lib_a-exit.o): In function 'exit':
exit.c:(.text.exit+0x16): undefined reference to '_exit'
C:\Users\MTYS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccECjb0N.o: In function 'Init_Adc':
C:\eclipse_workspace\proba\Debug/../main.c:20: undefined reference to 'SysCtlPeripheralEnable'`

And all of driver functions gave me error.

And my path is (windows path: C:\stellarisware\, the project folder is C:\eclipse_workspace\try):

`../../../stellarisware/
../../../stellarisware/utils
../../../stellarisware/driverlib
../../../stellarisware/inc/`

I tried different methods (use cygwin path, or absolute windows path), the code can be compiled successfully with IAR. What should I do?

Comment: Per the guide the arm-none-eabi is for ubuntu to Linux. So you will need to find the window variant. Also you need to down load the openocd for windows.